# Vuetify v-date-picker formatting is wonky - how can I fix?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

v-date-picker formatting is screwy.  The popup is chopped off at the bottom and there's a transparent gutter on the right hand side.  Is this a known bug?  The popup seems to always be the width of the container.  I removed all CSS and simplified the app to the test below.

```
<!-- the layout (admin.vue) -->
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <Nuxt class="ma-2"/>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<!-- the page -->
<template>
  <div>
    <v-menu :close-on-content-click="true" :nudge-right="40" transition="scale-transition" offset-y>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
        <v-text-field label="Date listed" prepend-icon="mdi-calendar" :value="form.dateListed" v-on="on"/>
      </template>
      <v-date-picker v-model.lazy="form.dateListed" locale="en-us" header-color="primary" tabindex="0"/>
    </v-menu>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  layout: 'admin',
    data() {
    return {
      form: {
      },
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCBRC.png)

Comment: i used this component a month ago and didn't had such issues. can you provide more css code maybe? or give us the whole component in a sandbox or something...

Comment: Please mention the vuetify version which you are using. Date Picker is working as intended why don't you remove the Tab Slider and check.

Comment: I moved the v-menu structure to a page inside only a div.  The associated v-text-field was as wide as the page and so was the v-date-picker popup.  The bottom row was still cut off.  I commented out all of my CSS styles.  I'm using Vue 2 and Vuetify with Nuxt.  It used to work but now it seems the popup always has the same width as its container.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `min-width: auto` to the `v-menu` like this:

```
<v-menu min-width="auto" v-model="menus.date">
...
</v-menu>
```